# static variable inside a static class and a static variable inside a non static class

Tags: c#, static

what is the difference between a static variable inside a static class and a static variable inside a non static class?

ex:

```
public static class GT
{
   public static readonly string x;
}


public class GT
{
   public static readonly string x;
}
```

Comment: The non static class can also contain instance variables.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead and in my case where i just need to include static variables in it, there is no difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference when you're talking about the actual variables inside the class. A static variable inside a static class is the same as a static variable inside a non static class.

On the other hand.. if you're talking about the classes themselves, then the static class cannot contain instance variables or methods.. it doesn't make sense.. since you cannot instantiate an instance of a static class yourself.

Comment: does a static class exist and its variables exist in memory as soon as i run the application or it will be initialized after the first time i call a method from it or a variable?

Comment: That is completely up to the implementation. If a static class has a static constructor, then it will be initialized immediately before it is first used (there are some caveats with that in .NET 4). If it doesn't, then it is up to the implementation on when to initialize it (still before it is used.. it just isn't determined when).